# quantum circuit

Tags: graphics

I need to draw the following quantum circuit. Is there anybody who can help me with that? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code that produces part of your diagram, but contains all elements that you need. I deliberately use only simple features that are mostly self explanatory. Complete the diagram. If problems remain that you cannot solve yourself, please come back, providing the code together with a problem description.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\ket[1]{$\left|#1\right>$}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1.5]
  \draw (0,0) node[left]{\ket{x}} -- (3,0) -- (5,-1)
    -- (6,-1) node[right]{\ket{\frac{y-x}{\sqrt2}}};
  \draw (1,-1.5) -- (2,-1) -- node[above]{\ket y} (3,-1)
    -- (5,0) -- (6,0) node[right]{\ket{\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}}};
  \draw[very thick] (3,-0.5)
    -- node[above]{$+$} node[below]{$-$} (5,-0.5);
  \node[draw] (boxednode) at (4,-2) {$1/\sqrt 2$};
  \draw (1,-1.5) -- (2,-2) -- node[above]{\ket z} (3,-2)
    -- (boxednode) --  (6,-2) node[right]{\ket{\frac{z}{\sqrt2}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]